# nothing happens when i submit a form in MEAN STACK

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, express, mean-stack

so the project is so simple. the user inputs some infos about a book and click submit to save the infos in a database (Mongodb) i'm using MEAN STACK and i'm a noobie (obviously). nothing happens when i submit not even an error.

**backend code :**

```
    //POST ONE BOOK
    booksRoute.route('/post').post((req,res,next)=>{
        var x = {
            name   : req.params.name,
            genre  : req.params.genre,   
            author : req.params.author,
            rating : req.params.rating,
            price  : req.params.price
        }
        console.log(x) ; 
        BookModel(x).save((err,data)=>{
            if (err){console.log(err);}
            else res.send(data) ;
}) ;
})
```

**add book component html :**

```
<ul>
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)">  
    <li>
    <label>book's name *</label>
    <input name="name" type="text" ngModel>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label>book's genre *</label>
    <input name="genre" type="text" ngModel>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label>book's author *</label>
    <input name="author" type="text" ngModel>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label>rating *</label>
    <input name="rating" type="number" [max]="10" min="0" ngModel>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label>price *</label>
    <input name="price" type="number" ngModel>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"/> 
    </li>  
</form>
</ul>
```

**angular service**

```
  postBook(data){
    console.log(data) ;
    return this.http.post(this.backendUrl+'/post',data) ;
  }
```

**in addBook component ts**

```
onSubmit(f){
    //console.log(f.value) ;
    this.apiService.postBook(f.value) ; 
  }
```

**Note** : i can get data from the database, i can find a book by it's name but i can't post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that You need to **subscribe** to the response of your API/back, something like this:

```
onSubmit(f){
    //console.log(f.value) ;
    this.apiService.postBook(f.value)
    .subscribe( res => {
     console.log('The back response:', res);
    }); 
}
```

Until you don't subscribe to the observable which has the *http call* to the API, is not going to "start" the http call process.

Comment: ur suggestion was correct thank u so much, but i can't understand the logic of this i mean, i thought that we subscribe to an observable to get the new value of it whenever it's value changes right ? but here we're posting data to the database, we're not sending it to the front page or anything, am i making sense here or am i completely wrong. damn this angular is confusing.

Comment: I understand your doubt because it is a bit "messy" at first, but it is the way it works: Until an observable is not subscribed to the http call, it will not start (and, therefore, the 'back' will not receive any signal, process the put, nor return the response that everything went OK,...).  I leave you an article about it, and I hope it helps you to have a better understanding of the subject: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-httpclient/